# shell script to compare two files and write the difference to third file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to compare two files and redirect the difference between the two files to third one.
file1:

```
  /opt/a/a.sql
  /opt/b/b.sql
  /opt/c/c.sql
```

In case any file has `#` before `/opt/c/c.sql`, it should skip `#`

file2:

```
 /opt/c/c.sql
 /opt/a/a.sql
```

I want to get the difference between the two files. In this case,  `/opt/b/b.sql` should be stored in a different file. Can anyone help me to achieve the above scenarios?

Comment: [`man diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html)

Comment: First you should decide which of the three you want to use: batch, powershell or shell script

Comment: Second, you should research what command(s) you would use for your scripting language choice.

Comment: i tried diff file file2, but not getting the expected result  i need only /opt/b/b.sql as output..is it possible? if possible can any one please help me...

Answer (score 1):

**file1**

```
$ cat file1 #both file1 and file2 may contain spaces which are ignored

/opt/a/a.sql
/opt/b/b.sql

/opt/c/c.sql
/opt/h/m.sql
```

**file2**

```
$ cat file2
/opt/c/c.sql
/opt/a/a.sql
```

**Do**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{line[$1];next} 
     {if(!($1 in line)){if($0!=""){print}}}
    ' file2 file1 > file3
```

**file3**

```
$ cat file3
/opt/b/b.sql
/opt/h/m.sql
```

**Notes:**

1. The order of files passed to awk is important here, pass the file to check - `file2` here - first followed by the master file -`file1`.
2. Check `awk` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Reference-to-Elements.html) to understand what is done here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some tools like `cat`, `sed`, `sort` and `uniq`.

The main observation is this: if the line is in *both files* then it is *not unique* in `cat file1 file2`.

Furthermore in `cat file1 file2| sort`, all doubles are in sequence. Using `uniq -u` we get unique lines and have this pipe:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -u
```

Using `sed` to remove leading whitespace, empty and comment lines, we get this final pipe:

```
cat file1 file2 | sed -r 's/^[ \t]+//; /^#/ d; /^$/ d;' | sort | uniq -u > file3
```